# Error de PHP "Warning: Undefined array key " en subida de imagen con $_FILES

Tags: php, array, imagen, undefined

Estoy aprendiendo PHP y copié el  código PHP de un video de *YouTube* puesto que me  pareció sencilo, sin embargo,  me da el error:

`Warning: Undefined array key "file" in C:\xampp\htdocs\TiendaVegana\index.php on line 348`.

El código es el siguiente:

### index.php

```
<form id="productoNuevoForm" action="nuevoProducto.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/formdata">

 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNombreProducto" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Nombre de producto" name="nombreProducto">
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPrecioProducto" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Precio" name="precioProducto">
  <br>
  Seleccionar imagen... <br>
  <input type="file" name="file" /> 
  <br>
  <br>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="btnAgregar" name="accionAgregar">Agregar</button>
            
  </form>
<?php

echo $_FILES['file']["name"];

?>
```

---

Quisiera poder entender por qué me sale el error si quiero cargar un archivo. Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues, tu error es sencillo no puedes hacer un echo a **$_FILES['file']["name"];**  Debido a que no existe.

En caso de que quieras subir una "x" img deberias de configurar eso en tu archivo que llamas: **nuevoProducto.php**

Comment: Pero tambien estoy intentando subiendo una imagen al formulario y luego clickeando en el submit pero aún asi me sigue tirando ese mismo error error :/

Comment: Ahi edité el código, el action está vacio ya que lo unico que hago es mas abajo en el mismo archivo, realizar un echo del nombre la imagen que quiero subir, pero simplemente me sigue tirando el error

Comment: Estaba revisando tu codigo en mi local, y me fije en un pequeño detalle que te falto en tu <form> y es que no es **enctype="multipart/formdata"** en realidad es **enctype="multipart/form-data"**

Comment: De igual forma, te seguira saliendo ese error  **Warning: Undefined array key "file"** en tu index, debido a que estas llamando una variable que **no existe.**

Comment: Ídolo!!!!! Mil graciassssss, no puedo creer que haya sido ese detalle jaja. Un saludo amigo

Comment: Perfecto amigo! Si te sirvio mi solucion, marca como respuesta mi comentario.